# Does {merge: true} send the entire document in the back end in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a specific feature I'm using that requires many (thousands) of small pieces of indexed data. Rather than fetching a thousand documents per startup and incurring unnecessary costs, I would like to simply download the whole giant document at once, and merge changes by key.

This means the document might approach the 1MB limit.

I have a curiosity about bandwidth though. I'm wondering if Firestore intelligently only sends/receives the most economical amount of the document. This means, for example, if I have 2000 entries in this one document, and I update one using {merge:true}, how much bandwidth will my browser use for this? Would it use only what's needed? Sending only the merged part rather than merging it in the background and sending the whole document?

And what about onSnapshot. For example, if I'm listening for changes in this large document, and it changes, and the new document is downloaded, is the onSnapshot logic behind the scenes smart enough to know to only download the necessary (changed) portion of the document rather than the full 1MB?

My users will be on data and I don't want to waste their data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `documentRef.set(..., { merge: true })` the Firestore SDK sends exactly what you pass as `...` to the server. The same happens when you call it without `{ merge: true }`.

An `onSnapshot` listener always received the complete document, regardless of what/how much has changed in that document.

---

So by merging the many small documents into a single document you are trading the cost of document reads for a cost in bandwidth consumption. Whether this trade-off is worth it, all depends on your use-case and data. I recommend using the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to determine the exact values.